# How to determine which Join point was called in advice? (Spring boot AOP)

Tags: java, spring, aop

Good afternoon!
Can you please tell me if there is a way in the Advice method to determine which JoinPoint was called?
The Advice method itself works with multiple JoinPoints.

Interested in something like this:

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "getExecutionAllControllerMethods() || getExecutionAllControllerAdviceMethods()",
            returning = "result")
public void logAfterReturningControllerResult(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
        if (getExecutionAllControllerAdviceMethods()) {
            log.info("1");
        } else if (getExecutionAllControllerMethods()) {
            log.debug("2");
        } else if .....
    }
```

Comment: the code you've shown makes no sense, since it's in both the if and else if the same condition.

Comment: what is stopping you from passing a parameter to your annotation?

Comment: @Stuluke, sorry, made a mistake.
Method in second condition 'getExecutionAllControllerMethods()'

Comment: create separate methods, pass a parameter to the annotation used to configure the joinpoint, ... what have you tried?

Comment: @Stultuske , there is not much experience with this aop technology so far.
Tell me, please, is there a way to determine which pointcut was called without using the annotation parameters?
In fact, I have one pointcut for intercepting events of calling controller methods, the second one - calling events of controller advice methods.

Comment: Why can't it be two different advice methods for the two pointcuts ? Also , the last `else if ...` appears to be an unreachable code per your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Let us review your situation, shall we?

- You are using a pointcut `a || b` with a logical OR.
- In order to remedy the situation that you do not know which of the two conditions - theoretically even both, because OR is not XOR - is true, you add an if-else construct in the advice body.
- I.e., you are introducing more complexity in your advice code in order to fight the complexity in your pointcut. You could easily expand that to pointcut `a || b || ... || z` and an if-else or switch-case statement with 26 branches.

Why make a simple thing complicated? Just use one advice per pointcut, and you shall never be in doubt which condition is true. If the advice code was as generic as you think it is, you would not need to care in the first place. If it makes a difference, however, don't force everything into a single advice. Simply problem, simple solution. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)! You can still factor out common code used in multiple advice bodies into a helper method, if that is your concern.